# How to get path of resource file and return it from jar file in eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, plugins

Here I am trying to add Help .html files on Cntl+space. Its working on my laptop because I have source code but not on server. No error but not returning path on server.

Here is my code:

```java
 Bundle  bundle=Platform.getBundle("my plugin ID");
  URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path("/doc/myfile/file/"), null);
  //Here in file folder my html files.
  String fPath = "";
     try {
            URL fileURL = FileLocator.toFileURL(url);
            fPath=fileURL.getPath();
         } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
   String fullPath = filePath + name+"."+ myfileextension;                  

        return fullPath;//returning myfile path
```

Answer (score 0):

You must give `FileLocator.toFileURL` the full name of the file you want, you can't use just the folder name.

This is because `FileLocator.find` may have to extract the file from the plug-in jar to a temporary location to make it available.

So:

```java
URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path("/doc/myfile/file/" + name + "." + myfileextension), null);
```

Also check your `build.properties` file. You must include all the folders you want to use in the plugin in this.

Comment: I added full name of the file. But still its not working. I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Check the build.properties file actually includes your doc folder in the plugin.

Comment: its giving NullPointerException .